# How to use angular 2 with redux and load the initial data in redux store from server before any component gets loaded?

Tags: angular, redux, redux-thunk

I am new to Angular2 and Redux development. I am trying to load initial data from server into redux store before any component gets loaded.
I think we can use angular2 APP_INITIALIZER to load initial data but not quite sure if that is the best approach.

Comment: How did you work it out?